# heroku db:push weird thing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku

So when I create an account on my RoR app locally, and then push it to heroku with `heroku db:push` all is well. However, when I make my account an admin with `User.find(5).toggle!(:admin)` locally in the console and then push the db to heroku, I can no longer log into my account. I get an incorrect pw and email combo. Why is this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this same problem with a tutorial.

When you update that admin user with toggle, it also updates the password salt based on the logic of the tutorial.  As a result, the password you setup correctly won't work.  The solution is to check your password salting methods and change your salting logic or post it here.

You can check to see if this the case yourself by going into the heroku ruby console and recording the user's salt prior to a toggle and post-toggle.  If you have the same problem I had they will be different.

Comment: Hi user564761, I just posted a similar problem and was hoping you could give me your thoughts on it when you get a chance, thanks!
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5463153/ruby-on-rails-why-does-the-users-encrypted-password-get-changed-in-the-db-when

Answer (score 0):

the database you use on your local computer is most likely the development.db, which depending on your configuration may or may not have been pushed to heroku.  check out [this article](http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/taps) for more info on how to specify which database you want to push to heroku.

Comment: hmmm... could it be that I'm setting admin in the console which goes to the test db only?

Comment: unless you are running your console in the test environment setting admin in console should set it in your development database.  remember also that heroku runs in production mode.  if you want to push specific data to your production environment i suggest either making a rake task to do that or setting the data in the production database on your local machine and then pushing that to heroku

Comment: how do I use the production database on my local machine?

Comment: if you wanted to access the production environment from console just do rails console production.  if that doesnt work for you there are plenty of other options out there to accomplish what you are trying to do already on SO just take a look at them.