# How to remove devise password resetting during email confirmation?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, email, devise, confirmation

My email confirmation works with devise, however I want to remove this automatic password resetting. I don't manage to find in which file devise orders this action. Thank you in advance !

Comment: What's the problem again?

Comment: Do you mean `Forgot your password?` functionality?

Comment: I think I did not write clearly, sorry. When I click on my link for email confirmation, it resets automatically password of the account whereas I do not want to.

Comment: It's ok now ! I thought it was because of devise but the problem was the encryption used in Michael Hartl's tutorial ! I found the solution here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5463153/ruby-on-rails-why-does-the-users-encrypted-password-get-changed-in-the-db-when

Answer (score 2):

Just disable `:recoverable` module in `User` model and remove *Forgot your password?* link in `devise/sessions/new.html.erb`

Comment: It seems you just have to remove :recoverable and the link will not be rendered

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want password recovery functionality in Devise, you should not set devise attribute ':recoverable' in your model. Please remove this attribute from your model, remove forgot password links from you views and you will no longer be able to reset password with Devise.

Answer (score 0):

Presuming your devise model is `User`:

1. Remove `:recoverable` module in `app/models/user.rb`
2. If you once had your devise views generated, remove `Forgot your password?` link in `app/views/devise/shared/_links.html.erb`
3. Create a migration dropping `reset_password_token` and `reset_password_sent_at` of your `users` table:

First run:

```
rails g migration RemoveRecoverableFromUsers
```

Edit migration:

```
class RemoveRecoverableFromUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def up
    remove_column :users, :reset_password_token
    remove_column :users, :reset_password_sent_at
  end

  def down
    add_column :users, :reset_password_token, :string
    add_column :users, :reset_password_sent_at, :datetime
  end
end
```