# Rails - Devise Gem remove Sign up and Forgot Password modules

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I work `Rails 4` with `Devise` gem for User authentication, In my project also working fine with `Devise` gem. But I want to remove the features of `Sign up` and `Forgot Password` modules.

For removing `sign_up`,
  In `config/routes.rb` file using `skip` option like,

```
devise :users, :skip => :registration
```

It removes the sign_up module also truncated `path generation`. This is fine.

But the same way, if I include this option for `Forgot password`

```
devise :users, :skip => :recover   
     or
devise :users, :skip => :recoverable
```

it won't work. I need to hide both modules in the same way of method.

How to achieve this? Thanks in advance..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove devise password resetting during email confirmation?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17672804/how-to-remove-devise-password-resetting-during-email-confirmation)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I got the answer,

In Devise `model` class remove the `devise :registerable, :recoverable` option.

Also do the changes in `devise/shared/_link.html.erb` by deleting the `path generation` links of `sign_up and forgot_password`