# Rails devise not able to register a second user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sql-server, devise

I'm using Rails with Devise and it is connecting to a MS SQL Server for the DB. This is all fine and working OK.

When I try to register a second person, I get the following error:

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique in Devise::RegistrationsController#create

TinyTds::Error: Cannot insert duplicate key row in object 'dbo.users' with
unique index 'index_users_on_reset_password_token'. The duplicate key value
is (<NULL>).: EXEC sp_executesql N'INSERT INTO [users] ([email],
[encrypted_password], [created_at], [updated_at]) OUTPUT INSERTED.[id] 
VALUES (@0, @1, @2, @3)', N'@0 nvarchar(4000), @1 nvarchar(4000), @2 
datetime, @3 datetime', @0 = N'ben_mcmaster@outlook.com', @1 = 
N'$2a$10$TK79.NSrjZaT93TiQphqB.M6XfBUlaGFmAqJUGgssdGggR4OB.7oC', @2 = '05-
09-2016 06:40:34.448', @3 = '05-09-2016 06:40:34.448'
```

I'm mainly looking at the fact that it is trying to create a new reset password token, but it is trying to make it NULL, as that already exists (in the first user).

In my app, doing a reset password is not really needed since I can do all that and there are only a couple of people.

Am I able to:

1. Get the app writing actual unique reset tokens
2. Bypass it

Answer (score 1):

From what  I understand you are okay with not having the whole 'Forgot Password' functionality in your application.
As described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17672804/how-to-remove-devise-password-resetting-during-email-confirmation) you need to remove the :recoverable option in your devise model, I think that should solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

I think problem is SQL Server.

On the one hand, Devise adds a unique index on user.reset_password_token by default. This allows users to use a reset password link with a one-time token to reset their password. Once that password has been reset, the field "reset_password_token" is reset to null.

On the other hand, standards said an UNIQUE constraint should disallow duplicate non-NULL values, but allow multiple NULL values. And SQL Server has always implemented a crippled version of this, allowing a single NULL but disallowing multiple NULL values.

In summary, if I were you, I would relaunch the migration in this way:

https://gist.github.com/andyhull/8045794202fd52930f93

I hope it useful for you.